# How to move a Line Renderer as its game object moves

Tags: unity

I created an empty game object and added a Line Renderer component to it through a script. I thought that once I adjust the position of the game object, it would do likewise for the line rendeder, but that is not the case.

I tried `useWorldSpace = false` but it totally changed the positions making the following points a straight line, though I was able to move the game object to to the line.

```
public Vector3 beginPos = new Vector3 (-1.0f, -1.0f, 0);
public Vector3 endPos = new Vector3 (1.0f, 1.0f, 0);
```

Is there a way I can convert points to input what I am more familiar with (so that points like the above points don't create a straight line) or should I be approaching the problem in a different way? I am open to a different approach.

**UPDATE**

I think I left an import detail. I'll be using lines made with line renderer to create shapes. So I need to be able to be able to move the lines around to move the shapes so I don't have to always recalculate the start and end points for the lines.

Comment: Are you sure `Use world space` is **unchecked** in the `LineRenderer` component?

Comment: @Hellium I just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure your LineRenderer component use World Position.
then in your Update() method just assign points positions (this code works for 5.6.0):

```
void Update(){
        if (usingLineRenderer) 
        {
            myLineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            if (hitBlocked == true) // we've hit something, so our line renderer end point should stop here
            {
                myLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, Hit.point);
            }
            else
            {
                myLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, transform.position + transform.forward * maxLaserDistance);
            }
        }

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out Hit, maxLaserDistance, ~ignoredLayers)){
             hitBlocked = true;
             // do stuff
        }
}
```

Particularly useful when using Virtual Reality Motion controllers, just assign it to the associated Hand Anchor.

Comment: I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1584085/view.html), you can [bake the line into mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html), then you can move the line (as mesh), here is the code from the post:

```
 public static void BakeLineDebuger(GameObject lineObj)
 {
     var lineRenderer = lineObj.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
     var meshFilter = lineObj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
     Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
     lineRenderer.BakeMesh(mesh);
     meshFilter.sharedMesh = mesh;

     var meshRenderer = lineObj.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
     meshRenderer.sharedMaterial = s_matDebug;

     GameObject.Destroy(lineRenderer);
 }
```

Make sure `lineObj` has `LineRenderer` component.

Answer (score 0):

Either update the line renderers positions yourself via script, or use a [Trail Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html)